# Journey Builder - Salesforce Entry Event

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm using the Salesforce Data based Entry Event in Journey Builder to pull in Salesforce contacts that have been created or updated. For created contacts it works great, as it pulls them in each time the contact is created. But for the updates, I noticed that the system forces you to have a filter criteria that evaluates to TRUE, otherwise it will ignore them.

The problem: The updates only work if the field is updated from something different than the condition, to something that equals the condition. Since the only fields I'm updating are date fields or unique number fields, it's impossible to predict what these dates or numbers will be for each user to have the filter criteria create a match.

Example: I want to add all contacts that update their First Name to NOT EQUAL John. Changing their first name from Sam to Sally appears to NOT meet this criteria and they will not be added into the Journey. Their name has to exist as John, then be changed to something that does NOT EQUAL John in order to qualify.

With that in mind, does anybody have any insight on how I can have use this functionality to meet my use case?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In the case of date fields I used Process Builder in Sales Cloud to add someone to a Campaign. In my case it was a Journey that should be triggered when someones warranty expires in 30 days. I used Process Builder to add someone as a Campaign Member when the condition is met and each Campaign Member was injected into a Journey based on the Create/Update rule of the Entry Event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it does seem as though making a workflow in Salesforce will need to be the solution. Although in my case there isn't even a known date, such as "expires in 30 days" - it's just a date field could be updated with ANYTHING, and I need that to add them to a workflow each time it is updated. I will keep trying things out to see if I can make the system work to my will!

Answer (score 2):

Found my ideal solution - using one of the Salesforce Activities within Journey Builder we can manually update a field in Salesforce with whatever we like.

So using my example, after a contact completes the Journey I would set their First Name to John, and the next time their First Name is changed it will automatically trigger the Entry Event.

Thanks!

Comment: This was super helpful!!